# Informar valor de field TFDAutoIncField usando FDQuery

Tags: firedac

Ola, Utiliso MySQL e estou migrando meus projeto do Delphi 2007 + Zeos para Delphi Berlin + FireDAC (grande mudança eim) e devido a algumas regras de negócio, campos auto increment do MySQL podem ser informado pelo usuario. ex: O campo IdProduto é um *bigint(20) not null autoinc*, mas devido a regras do governo esse campo pode ser preenchido manualmente pelo cliente, no Zeos isso não era um problema, bastava eu informar o valor e pronto.

No FireDAC campos autoinc não constam no SQL de Insert no FDUpdateSQL. Para informar manualmente o valor o campo eu tenho que alterar as propriedades ServerAutoIncrement e ClientAutoIncrement para False e incluir manualmente o campo no SQL do Insert, mas sempre que precisar criar um novo campo na tabela terei de me preocupar em incluir o campo no SQL do Insert, alem de sujeito a falhas essa abordagem tem toda a cara de uma POG.

Gostaria de saber qual a configuração correta (FDQuery, campo e FDUpdateSQL) para ter um campo AutoInc e ainda ser capaz de informa-lo manualmente quando necessário.